# Generar nuevo array recorriendo un objeto con metadatos dinamicos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con un objeto y tengo un metodo en mi API que guarda la información deseada de ese objeto. Primero le doy formato a ese objeto creando un nuevo array y luego lo guardo en la base de datos, todo esto con NodeJS y MongoDB.

Mi problema viene a la hora de crear el nuevo array con metadatos que no tengo definidos.

Hago lo siguiente recorro contextResponses para guardar el ID posteriormente recorro los attributes ya que es la información que necesito guardar todo esto sin problema, mi problema viene a la hora de recorrer los metadatas en este ejemplo como podéis apreciar tengo timestamp y id. Cuando recorro los dos metadatas tengo un IF que comprueba de qué tipo son los metadatas y los guardo en una varibale todo esto y luego lo paso a un nuevo array para guardarlo sin problema. Mi problema viene y en el caso que el usuario tenga más metadatas por ejemplo nombre o localización tal y como lo tengo guardaria id y timestamp ya que entra en IF. No los otros campos no tiene sentido tener tantos IF ademas de que no sabría cuales son. ¿Como podria hacerlo de forma independiente?.

Adjunto mi codigo al final.

```
    {
   "subscriptionId":"5d4ac37ea282bde1a8c8af50",
   "originator":"localhost",
   "contextResponses":[
      {
         "contextElement":{
            "type":"typopruebas99borrar",
            "isPattern":"false",
            "id":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "name":"Altitude",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":70.5,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"23_X_X_652_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"CO2",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":402,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_avg"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"CO2_max",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":402,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_max"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"CO2_min",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":402,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_min"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Horizontal_dilusion_of_position",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":1,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"24_X_X_659_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Latitude",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":36.847452,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"21_X_X_650_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Longitude",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":-2.285061,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"22_X_X_651_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Nivel_bateria",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":6169,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"7_X_X_7_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Panel_solar",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":6451,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"4_X_X_30_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Radiacion_solar",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":222,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180101"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"11_X_X_600_avg"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Sensor_placa_bateria",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":3706,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"2000_001EC095748E_X_33798_last"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Sensor_placa_solar",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":9109,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"Integer",
                        "value":"1565180100"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"2001_001EC095748E_X_33799_last"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "statusCode":{
            "code":"200",
            "reasonPhrase":"OK"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Codigo**

```
for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
                //console.log('Mostramos el array:', params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas)
                if (params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name === 'timestamp') {
                    var recvTimeTs = params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value;
                    var recvTime = new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).toISOString();
                }
                if ((params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name === 'id')) {
                    var name_fiware = params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value;
                }
                var medidas_inver = {
                    id_station: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id,
                    fiware_service: paramsheadersFiware_Service,
                    fiware_servicepath: paramsheadersFiware_ServicePath,
                    attrName: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
                    id_sensor_station_absolute: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name.concat("_", params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id),
                    attrType: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
                    attrValue: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
                    recvTimeTs: recvTimeTs,
                    recvTime: recvTime,
                    name_fiware: name_fiware
                };
                data_inver.push(medidas_inver);
                console.log('Mostramos las medidas:', JSON.stringify(data_inver));
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: Primero deberías desacoplar tu código, hacer que por cada "type" te lo resuelva una función que le envies parámetros y te retorne según como lo quieras resolver. y en vez de anidar if's, usa una estructura switch, supongo que el tratamiento de un dato está diferenciado por la propiedad "type", de ese modo tendrías una estructura más escalable y mantenible, por que tu mismo te estás dando cuenta que se esta volviendo una bomba de tiempo.

Comment: No me queda claro qué quieres lograr, ¿cómo te gustaría tratar otros metadatos? El timestamp lo transformas a String, el id lo dejas tal cual... ¿qué harías con el resto si no sabes de qué tipo son?

Comment: Hola Pablo, he mirado las respuesta y ninguna vale para lo que yo necesito. Edito el Post

Answer (score 1):

La mejor solución sería utilizar un `switch` en el cual vas indicando que operación realizar en cada caso

```js
const data = {
    "subscriptionId": "5d4ac37ea282bde1a8c8af50",
    "originator": "localhost",
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "type": "typopruebas99borrar",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "pruebas999borrar22224442222333",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "Altitude",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 70.5,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "23_X_X_652_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CO2",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 402,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_avg"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CO2_max",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 402,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_max"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CO2_min",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 402,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_min"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Horizontal_dilusion_of_position",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 1,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "24_X_X_659_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Latitude",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 36.847452,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "21_X_X_650_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Longitude",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": -2.285061,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "22_X_X_651_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Nivel_bateria",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 6169,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "7_X_X_7_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Panel_solar",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 6451,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "4_X_X_30_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Radiacion_solar",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 222,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180101"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "11_X_X_600_avg"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Sensor_placa_bateria",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 3706,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "2000_001EC095748E_X_33798_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Sensor_placa_solar",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": 9109,
                        "metadatas": [
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "Integer",
                                "value": "1565180100"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "2001_001EC095748E_X_33799_last"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}

let res = []
    data.contextResponses[0].contextElement.attributes.filter(x => {
        x.metadatas.map(m => {
            let aux = { }
            switch (m.name) {
                case 'timestamp':
                    aux.recvTimeTs = m.value
                    aux.recvTime = new Date(m.value * 1000).toISOString()
                    break;
                case 'id':
                    aux.name_fiware = m.value
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('No hay')
                    break;
            }
            res.push(aux)
        })
    })
    console.log(res)
```

Adicionalmente elimine los `for` que estabas utilizando, y los reemplace por *programación funcional* utilizando los métodos súper útiles de **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)** y **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)**; de esta forma simplificamos mucho la eficiencia de nuestro código

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas

Comment: ¿Por qué usas map y filter? deberías usar `forEach` en ambos casos, puesto que no hay ni un solo `return` que justifique el uso de las funciones citadas

Comment: :O ignoraba por completo que para usar esas funciones se debiera usar por obligación un `return` @PabloLozano . Veré como adapto el código para dejarlo como corresponde. Agradecido por la valiosa aclaración :)

Answer (score 1):

He refactorizado tú código a algo más legible y mantenible, la salida es la misma, en adelante para hacer lo que buscas tendrías que agregar cases al switch de acuerdo al `name` que quieres tratar.
Espero esté claro que:

- `cr` equivale a: `contextResponses`
- `a` equivale a: `attributes`
- `m` equivale a: `metadatas`

```js
const params={subscriptionId:"5d4ac37ea282bde1a8c8af50",originator:"localhost",contextResponses:[{contextElement:{type:"typopruebas99borrar",isPattern:"false",id:"pruebas999borrar22224442222333",attributes:[{name:"Altitude",type:"float",value:70.5,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"23_X_X_652_last"}]},{name:"CO2",type:"float",value:402,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_avg"}]},{name:"CO2_max",type:"float",value:402,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_max"}]},{name:"CO2_min",type:"float",value:402,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"2004_001EC095C730_X_34049_min"}]},{name:"Horizontal_dilusion_of_position",type:"float",value:1,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"24_X_X_659_last"}]},{name:"Latitude",type:"float",value:36.847452,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"21_X_X_650_last"}]},{name:"Longitude",type:"float",value:-2.285061,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"22_X_X_651_last"}]},{name:"Nivel_bateria",type:"float",value:6169,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"7_X_X_7_last"}]},{name:"Panel_solar",type:"float",value:6451,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"4_X_X_30_last"}]},{name:"Radiacion_solar",type:"float",value:222,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180101"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"11_X_X_600_avg"}]},{name:"Sensor_placa_bateria",type:"float",value:3706,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"2000_001EC095748E_X_33798_last"}]},{name:"Sensor_placa_solar",type:"float",value:9109,metadatas:[{name:"timestamp",type:"Integer",value:"1565180100"},{name:"id",type:"String",value:"2001_001EC095748E_X_33799_last"}]}]},statusCode:{code:"200",reasonPhrase:"OK"}}]};

let data_inver = [];

params.contextResponses.forEach(cr => {
  cr.contextElement.attributes.forEach(a => {
    // attrs a setear cada iteración de metadatas
    let recvTimeTs = null;
    let recvTime = null;
    let name_fiware = null;

    a.metadatas.forEach(m => {
      // switch a cada metadata name
      switch (m.name) {
        case "timestamp":
          recvTimeTs = m.value;
          recvTime = new Date(m.value * 1000).toISOString();
          break;
        case "id":
          name_fiware = m.value;
          break;
      }

      // push a data_inver la recopilación de datos
      data_inver.push({
        id_station: cr.contextElement.id,
        fiware_service: params.headersFiware_Service,
        fiware_servicepath: params.headersFiware_ServicePath,
        attrName: a.name,
        id_sensor_station_absolute: a.name.concat("_", cr.contextElement.id),
        attrType: a.type,
        attrValue: a.value,
        recvTimeTs,
        recvTime,
        name_fiware
      });
    });
  });
});

console.log(data_inver);
```